# onclick not firing on first click

Tags: javascript, onclick

**Note:** There are a few similar questions and answers on this topic but they all seem to apply to more complex problems and issues.  This one is very simple.

The first time I click my button the javascript function doesn't fire.  On the second click and each click thereafter it works as expected.  I'm sure that I'm missing something simple but I can't spot the problem.

```js
function changeStyle() {  
 
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[1];
  
    if (a.style.backgroundColor === 'blue') {
     a.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    } else {
     a.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
  
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="changeStyle()"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Your element has no inline style on the first click. Change it to `if (!a.style.backgroundColor) {...` and then in the `else` do `a.style.backgroundColor = ""`

Comment: Or perhaps better, use classes instead of applying direct styles.

Comment: To further explain, a good [quote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#Getting_style_information) : `The style property is not useful for completely learning about the styles applied on the element, since it represents only the CSS declarations set in the element's inline style attribute, not those that come from style rules elsewhere, such as style rules in the <head> section, or external style sheets` - basically, `a.style` does not have the information from your css file accessible in it, so your `if` statement evaluates as false first.

Comment: @squint I bet you're right that for some reason the element doesn't realize that it has a style before the first click.  But in the style I wrote `background-color: blue;'.  I'm not sure why changing the script from `(a.style.backgroundColor === 'blue')` to `(a.style.backgroundColor)` would fix it.

Comment: Because, like I mentioned, `a.style.backgroundColor` doesn't exist _at all_ when you first run- the `style` property is **not** connected to the style that your CSS is applying.

Comment: @KarlReid Super interesting! I didn't know that .style only applied to inline styles.  Is there a command that applies to external styles?

Comment: [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) , I think.

Comment: But as other users are saying, the standard way to do this is to use classes, instead of directly changing properties. So something like having `redcontainer` and `bluecontainer` classes in your CSS and using your JS code to change the element from one to the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since on first click there is style.background='', it remains blue even when event is firing. Here is a one way to solve it.

```js
function changeStyle() {  
 
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[1];
    if (a.style.backgroundColor === 'blue' || a.style.backgroundColor === '') {
     a.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    } else {
     a.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
  
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="changeStyle()"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Using the `||` or command is brilliant.  That's a smart/simple way to solve that.

Answer (score 1):

`a.style` refers to inline styles applied to the element. You have several options to solve this problem:

1) use classes to change the color

```js
function changeStyle() {  
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[1];
    a.classList.toggle("red");
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="changeStyle()"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

2) use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(a);
console.log(style["background-color"]);
```

The problem with this solution is, that you have no idea, how the browser will report the color (hex-color, rgb color, color name,...), so you possibly have to check for `#0000ff`, `rgb(0,0,255)` or `blue`. I think toggling the classes is by far the easiest and cleanest solution.

Comment: Using `.toggle` is a smart and simple solution.  I'm going to read more on that.  One problem I've had with toggle before is that unless the "toggled" class is written below the initial class it doesn't necessarily change the style.

Comment: Then you need to set the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) accordingly.